# Using the <#ftl> directive in a freemarker template

Tags: spring, encoding, character-encoding, freemarker

I'm trying to have Freemarker parse my template files as UTF-8, but it seems to be always parsing them as Cp1252.

```
2013-07-30 00:00:00.984 DEBUG freemarker.cache:? Could not find template in cache, creating new one; id=["myFile.ftl"["es_MX",Cp1252,parsed] ]
```

I searched and [found that adding the FTL directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html#ref.directive.ftl) allows me to specify the encoding.

I added it to the template file (saved in UTF-8 with BOM in Notepad++) like so:

```
<#ftl encoding="UTF-8">
Estimado Usuario,
Testing this content!
<#/ftl>
```

But get this in the log.

```
MessageTemplateException [message=Unable to process template due to Encountered "<#ftl " at line 1, column 4 in myFile.ftl.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <ATTEMPT> ...
    <IF> ...
    <LIST> ...
    <FOREACH> ...
    <SWITCH> ...
    <ASSIGN> ...
    <GLOBALASSIGN> ...
    <LOCALASSIGN> ...
    <_INCLUDE> ...
    <IMPORT> ...
    <FUNCTION> ...
    <MACRO> ...
    <TRANSFORM> ...
    <VISIT> ...
    <STOP> ...
    <RETURN> ...
    <CALL> ...
    <SETTING> ...
    <COMPRESS> ...
    <COMMENT> ...
    <TERSE_COMMENT> ...
    <NOPARSE> ...
    <BREAK> ...
    <SIMPLE_RETURN> ...
    <HALT> ...
    <FLUSH> ...
    <TRIM> ...
    <LTRIM> ...
    <RTRIM> ...
    <NOTRIM> ...
    <SIMPLE_NESTED> ...
    <NESTED> ...
    <SIMPLE_RECURSE> ...
    <RECURSE> ...
    <FALLBACK> ...
    <ESCAPE> ...
    <NOESCAPE> ...
    <UNIFIED_CALL> ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    <PRINTABLE_CHARS> ...
    <FALSE_ALERT> ...
    "${" ...
    "#{" ...
 with inputs of {loginUrl=testURL} in myFile.ftl with locale es_MX, code=SUCCESS, arguments=[]]
```

Maybe I'm not doing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use BOM. Also don't use `</#ftl>`, there's only `<#ftl>`. But most importantly, if most of your templates are in UTF-8, just set the default encoding of FreeMarker to UTF-8 (in Spring, something like `<bean         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">...<property name="freemarkerSettings">...<props>...<prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>`), so your don't need to use `#ftl` because of this.

Comment: `<#ftl encoding="utf-8">` throws an error `Encountered "<#ftl ", but was expecting one of:` and a list of directives. Can't set this in spring since those templates were used in a proprietary application from IBM.

Comment: @Daniel What FreeMarker version is that? What does `${.version}` print?

Comment: Seems v2.3.28 according to the jars in WebSphere nodes folder. It's from an IBM Connections on prem installation. `${.version}` gave me an error that it doesn't exist. It seems that IBM messes again with core modifications...

Comment: But I found a workaround by escaping special characters with `\u` like `\u00E4` for ´ä´. This was the main reason for the `<#ftl` tag since I assumed something went wrong with the encoding.

Comment: @Daniel FreeMarker doesn't even support `\u`. I assume that wasn't in the template, but in data source it shows. If it doesn't know `${.version}`, then that's some very very old version. I guess you have another freemarker jar somewhere that takes priority.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and finally found a way to use the <#ftl> directive, so in case the same thing happens to anyone :

My problem was that I didn't put the <#ftl> directive on top of my template. As soon as I put it on the first line of my template, everything worked like a charm.